# Are rx relays never disposed?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, dispose

Reading up on `Rx relays` it says that they never complete or emit errors: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/main/Documentation/Subjects.md

1. Does that mean that they will never dispose unless you dispose them manually, like so:

```
let disposable: Disposable?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    disposable = viewModel.myRelay.subscribe(onNext: { //do stuff })
}

override func viewWillDisappear() {
    super.viewWillDisappear()

    disposable.dispose()
}
```

2. So hooking on `.dispose(by: disposeBag)` is pointless, right?
3. Won't relays create memory leaks unless they are `disposed` manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A subscription will dispose when its source emits a stop event (either completed or error) or its disposable's `dispose()` is called. You are correct that Relays never emit stop events, so the only way to release the subscriptions sourced from a relay is to dispose them.

To dispose such a subscription, you can do it manually, *or* you can insert the disposable into a dispose bag. A DisposeBag calls `dispose()` on all the disposables it contains when it is `deinit`ed. So:

```
final class Example: UIViewController { 
    let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    override func viewDidLoad() { 
        super.viewDidLoad()
        viewModel.myRelay
            .subscribe(onNext: { /* do stuff */ })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Is sufficient, and best practice.